# TabItem ViewController Transition Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to set to a UITabItem's view controller the Cover Vertical Transition style.
I've set it up when setting the tab bar view controllers and also in the view controller's viewWillAppear but it doesn't work.

I've tried doing

```
self.viewControllers?[2].modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
```

and

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
```

in the viewWillAppear of the specific ViewController

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please post some code on what you've tried.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: What class' `viewWillAppear` is this code present in?

Comment: in self.viewControllers[2] class

Comment: @PabloRomero That doesn't make sense. If it is in the viewController referenced by `self.viewControllers[2]` then `self` would equal `self.viewControllers[2]` which propels us into a paradox.

Comment: What I meant is that i set the transition style when setting the tab bar's view controllers AND ALSO did self.modalTransitionStyle in the viewWillAppear of that specific view controller's class